# How to post form with ajax after form validate?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I try to post my form with ajax.But when i use click instead of submit in jquery part, it works but this time form hasnt validate. when i use submit this this ajax doesn't trigger after validation.Whats wrong?

```html
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="Name" name="Name" aria-describedby="Name" required />
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="Surname" class="h6">Surname</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control " id="Surname" name="Surname" aria-describedby="Surname" required />
</div>

<button id="btnAddUser" name="btnAddUser" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary float-right">Add User</button>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#btnAddUser').submit(function() {
    var user = {};
    user.Name = $('#Name').val();
    user.Surname = $('#Surname').val();
    user.ActiveDirectory = $('#ActiveDirectory').val();
    user.Role = $('#Role').val();
    user.Status = $('#Status').val();

    $.ajax({
      url: '/Processes.asmx/addUser',
      method: 'post',
      data: '{usr: ' + JSON.stringify(user) + '}',
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      success: function() {

        alert('Success');
      },
      error: function(err) {
        alert(err);
      }
    });
    return false;
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is because `button` elements do not raise a `submit` event. To fix your issue you need to wrap the controls in a `form` element then hook your JS to the `submit` event of that, like this:

```html
<form action="/yourpage" method="POST">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Name" name="Name" aria-describedby="Name" required />

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="Surname" class="h6">Surname</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control " id="Surname" name="Surname" aria-describedby="Surname" required />
  </div>

  <button id="btnAddUser" name="btnAddUser" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary float-right">Add User</button>
</form>
```

```js
jQuery($ => {
  $('form').on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var user = {
      Name: $('#Name').val(),
      Surname: $('#Surname').val();
      ActiveDirectory: $('#ActiveDirectory').val();
      Role: $('#Role').val();
      Status: $('#Status').val();
    };

    $.ajax({
      url: '/Processes.asmx/addUser',
      method: 'post',
      data: '{usr: ' + JSON.stringify(user) + '}',
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      success: function() {
        console.log('Success');
      },
      error: function(err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

I would also suggest you review how you create the data you send in the AJAX request. Encoding JSON manually is a code smell, along with nesting JSON *within* JSON.

Depending on the model binding you're using in your WebMethod and the form HTML, you could simplify it to just `data: $(this).serialize()`.

Comment: i use master page thats in content page so there is no form tag and there one more button too in same page for editing users
     <button id="btnEditUser" name="btnEditUser" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary float-right">Edit</button>
                                        <button id="btnAddUser" name="btnAddUser" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary float-right">Add</button>

Comment: Can you not add the `<form>` tag...? Use `type="button"` for the other actions which don't relate to the form content, or better yet, move them outside the form and make them `a` elements.

Comment: But need to required fields for edituser button when i try to your code it worked but also when i click edit user, behaviour like add user button

Comment: That's why I said make it a `type="button"` or an `a` element instead